# Class A uses class B. Class C contains an instance of A (composition). Should the diagram reflect the fact that C is dependent on A?

Tags: uml, observer-pattern

I made a simple 2-window UI to practice the Observer pattern (which I hopefully managed to implement correctly):

- a window with some text fields meant for adding a new book to a list
- another one displaying the list itself, which gets updated automatically when a new book is added

I'm confused about the way the relationship between the **BookInput** class and the **Book** class should be represented. The former doesn't have any methods using the **Book** objects directly, but it does contain a **Library** object, which is dependent on the **Book** class. Is its dependency, therefore, implicit, or should there be another dashed arrow between **BookInput** and **Book**?

Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### On UML model

You would **not show an indirect dependency** from `BookInput` to `Book`, because in principle, both are **decoupled**. In other words, you could change `Library` to use some `PrintedMedia` instead of `Book` and this would not impact to `BookInput`, at least based on your diagram and narrative.  Things would be different if there would be some coupling, for example if `BookInput` would create new books to be added to the `Library`. You'd then have a `«create»` dependency.  But this is not what your story tells us.

You SHOULD make an **association** between `Library` and `Book`:  it's a one-to-many association that is hidden in your attribute `books: vector<Book>` (which in UML should by the way be written `books: Book[0..*]`) that would replace the dependency on the diagram.

You COULD then show a **[derived](https://etutorials.org/Programming/UML/Chapter+6.+Class+Diagrams+Advanced+Concepts/Derived+Associations+and+Attributes/) association** between `BookInput` and `Book`, with a `/` in front of the derived association name.  But you would only do this in **exceptional** circumstance, if this is very important for your design, for example if `BookInput` would have some methods accessing the related books;  usually it's not necessary to show it because navigating between related objects is quite obvious.

### On the pattern

Normally, with the [observer pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/amp/observer-pattern/), there should be a navigable association between the observable and the observer, since the observable would need to know which observers to notify.

Answer (score 5):

UML diagrams are a communication and design tool. Anyone familiar with UML class diagrams should be able to know that BookInput holds a reference to Library, and Library depends on Book. The lines and symbols clearly state this in the diagram.

Typically you only connect immediate relationships in UML, otherwise UML diagrams will look like a shattered pane of glass. It is common to expect readers to trace through the trail of dependencies, otherwise the diagram becomes too cluttered with lines.

That isn't to say you should *never* do this. It all comes back to communication. If adding an extra dependency line helps communicate this, then add the connection. Just be aware that the more you add to the diagram, the harder it is to read. When the diagram becomes too cluttered, consider splitting the diagram up into multiple modules. There are many ways to split it up (along business lines, architecture, application module, etc).

Answer (score -1):

I think you are confusing yourself here.

On the left side, you have a window allowing you to enter information about a book and adding it to the library. It's not the "Book" class. It's a BookEditor.

On the right side, you have a window displaying a list of all books.

The "Library" should send a notification when someone adds or removes a book from the library, and classes that for example display the library or parts of it should observe it. Removing a book from the library would have to be done very carefully, for example what would you do if I rented a book from the library, and then it is "removed" from the library?

And the "Library" should send a notification when a book in the library is persistenly modified. For example if I return a book, then the viewer showing all the books should change its display for that book.

Comment: Right, so the BookEditor you referred to is what I called BookInput in the diagram, isn't it? I did not consider the intricacies of editing/removing/borrowing books, since I just wanted to test the "add element, see update" mechanic. If I understand it correctly, you're saying that making Library a field in the BookInput class is not a good idea?